# spark scala Date conversion

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, date

I have dataFrame with date format `DDMONYYYY`, it needs to be converted into date format with formatting `YYYY-MM-DD`

Can any one help me to resolve this issue

```scala
val df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
      ("steak", "1990-01-01", "30Mar2022", 150),
      ("steak", "2000-01-02", "13Jan2021", 180),
      ("fish",  "1990-01-01", "01Feb2001", 100)
    )).toDF("name", "startDate", "endDate", "price")

df.show()

df.select(date_format(col("endDate"), "MM/dd/yyyy")).show
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **to_date** and **date_format** functions provided by Spark.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("endDate", to_date(col("endDate"), "ddMMMyyyy"))
  .withColumn("endDate", date_format(col("endDate"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))

df2.show()
```

The first withColumn converts the *"endDate"* column to a date type using the **"ddMMMyyyy"** pattern. The second withColumn converts the date to a string using the **"yyyy-MM-dd"** pattern.

```
+-----+----------+----------+-----+
| name| startDate|   endDate|price|
+-----+----------+----------+-----+
|steak|1990-01-01|2022-03-30|  150|
|steak|2000-01-02|2021-01-13|  180|
| fish|1990-01-01|2001-02-01|  100|
+-----+----------+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

The below steps also worked well.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("endDate", expr(" date_format(to_date(endDate, 'ddMMMyyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') "))
```